# Exception while running Bamboo Plugin

Tags: java, plugins, bamboo

I am developing a bamboo plugin, while running this plugin.
This is the error that I get:

java.lang.LinkageError : loader constraint violation: when resolving method "com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.setContentHandler(Lorg/xml/sax/ContentHandler;)V" the class loader (instance of org/apache/felix/framework/ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) for resolved class, com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder, have different Class objects for the type used in the signature)

Any clue or Suggestion on how to resolve this?
Thanks in Advance,
Abhishek